# Empty an existing NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Now I have an numpy array `X` with certain column names, format and length. How can I set all the values to `0` (or empty) in this array, without deleting the format/names etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`numpy.ndarray.fill`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a.fill(0)
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: What about Np.Zeroslike

Comment: That would create an entirely new array

Comment: @NickT, add `@agconti` to notify him/her.

Comment: @NickT you can use `myArray = np.zeros_like(myArray)`, it works the same I think.

Comment: @heltonbiker you're still creating an entirely new array then releasing the old one to get GC'd.  Will use twice as much memory and probably take longer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use slicing:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> a[:] = 0
>>> a
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.zeroes_like`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html#numpy.zeros_like) to create a new array, filled with zeroes but retaining type information from your existing array:

```
zeroed_X = numpy.zeroes_like(X)
```

If you want, you can save that type information from your structured array for future use too. It's all in the `dtype`:

```
my_dtype = X.dtype
```

Comment: Useful perhaps, but if someone wants to simply "empty" the array, it's better to `.fill()` it with something--you don't double the memory usage.